How can I preserve state in a `use`d module relatively to the `use`ing module without refactoring?
This is simplified example and not the actual case.
Currently I have a utility module (let's call it Z), which declares a number of functions and holds some state variable (let's call it Print) in a variable:
package Z;

use strict;
use warnings;

use feature qw(say);

our $Print;

sub test {
    say @_ if $Print;
}

1;

This obviously done so that printing of some stuff may be turned on / off by the useing module.
This is a utility module, so it's being used by many modules. For example, X and Y which, respectively, don't and do desire printing:
package X;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Z;

$Z::Print = 0; # Sets Z::Print to 0

sub f {
    Z::test(@_);
}

1;

package Y;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Z;

$Z::Print = 1; # Sets Z::Print to 1

sub f {
    Z::test(@_);
}

1;

Obviously this leads to problems when, e.g., X and Y are both used in the same script, as, e.g. in this case, Y will "step on X's foot" by changing the value of Z::Print globally:
#!/usr/bin/env perl

# test.pl

use strict;
use warnings;

use X;
use Y;

my $v = 0;

X::f($v);
Y::f($v);

user@server ~/[REDACTED] (git)-[REDACTED] % ./test.pl
0 # X prints, unwanted
0 # Y prints, wanted


In reality, X and Y are actually about 10 modules that rely on this Z module, and all these dependants are either classes comprised of a number of methods or "bundles" of functions; most methods / functions of these dependants rely on Z for something.

I know (as the statement in bold itself hints at) that Z could be (and should be) refactored into a class, and that I could instantiate a local copy of Z in X and Y; this is undesirable at this point in time, because it's a lot of work;
Holding a state variable in X and Y to control Z's behavior would be fine, however that would also require a huge refactor of Z's functions; this is, too, undesirable at this point in time;
I'm looking for an alternate, faster solution to the solutions proposed above (if it's possible to fix this at all), even though I know changing the design would be the "correct" solution.
I'm aware this could've been a bad design choice on my side. Still, that's we're I'm at right now, and I'm wondering if there's a, at least temporary, easy way out.

I'll appreciate any inputs. Thank you

Holding a state variable in X and Y to control Z's behavior would work if you reset the $Z::Print variable from inside f(). But of course making it OO would be the better way to go.

@clamp true, the problem is: X and Y have lots of functions / methods relying on Z (and really X and Y are mentioned just for the sake of describing the problem and the structure of the dependencies of this project, the truth is that, in fact, there's a lot more modules that rely on Z). So that also, unfortunately, in this case, becomes a sloppy, error-prone and time consuming fix to apply. I'll update the question to better convey this complexity. Thank you for your suggestion

@Shawn Yeah I thought of that too, I guess that would limit the refactor to modules X and Y (that in reality would mean refactoring a lot more modules since this Z module is used everywhere). sigh Thank you for your input, I guess I'll have to consider this if no one pulls a rabbit out of the hat

Re "I'm looking for an alternate, faster solution to the solutions proposed above", Did you mean "you're NOT looking ..."?

You could use local in each of the callers that needs $Z::Print to be set.
sub f {
   local $Z::Print = 1;
   Z::test( @_ );
}


Here's an approach that reduces the changes the to caller, but requires changes to Z.
In the caller, replace
$Z::Print = 1;

with
our $Z_Print = 1;

In Z, remove
our $Print;

and replace
$Print

with
Print

and add
# Look up the call stack for the first package that's not this module.
sub _get_caller {
   for ( my $i = 1; ; ++$i ) {
      my $caller = caller( $i );
      return __PACKAGE__ if !defined( $caller );
      return $caller if $caller ne __PACKAGE__;
   }
}

my $prefix = __PACKAGE__ =~ s/::/_/gr;  # Or whatever.

sub Print :lvalue {
   my $caller = _get_caller();
   my $name = "${caller}::${prefix}_Print";
   no strict qw( refs );
   $$name
}


That said, your exacting requirements can be met. This requires using magic.
In Z, replace
our $Print;

with
use Variable::Magic qw( wizard cast );

# Look up the call stack for the first package that's not this module.
sub _get_caller {
   for ( my $i = 1; ; ++$i ) {
      my $caller = caller( $i );
      return __PACKAGE__ if !defined( $caller );
      return $caller if $caller ne __PACKAGE__;
   }
}

# In `get` and `set`,
# `$_[0]` is ref to the magic variable.
# `$_[1]` is the hash ref returned by `data`.
my $wiz = wizard(
   data => sub { return { }; },
   get  => sub { ${ $_[0] } = $_[1]->{ _get_caller() }; return; },
   set  => sub { $_[1]->{ _get_caller() } = ${ $_[0] }; return; },
);

cast( our $Print, $wiz );


data is called when the magic is added to $Print. It's a constructor of sorts. The value returned will be provided to future calls to the get and set callbacks associated with the variable.
get is called when $Print is read. The value read is the value of $Print after this call, which is allowed to change the value of $Print.
set is called after $Print is modified.

The same $wiz can be used for multiple variables.  And we can add support for defaults.
my $wiz = wizard(
   data => sub {
      my $var_ref = shift;
      my %data = @_;
      $data->{ default } = 0   if !exists( $data->{ default } );
      $data->{ backend } = { } if !exists( $data->{ backend } );
      return \%data;
   },

   get => sub {
      my $var_ref = shift;
      my $data    = shift;

      my $default = $data->{ default };
      my $backend = $data->{ backend };

      my $caller = _get_caller();

      if ( !exists( $backend->{ $caller } ) ) {
         $backend->{ $caller } = $default;
      }

      $$var_ref = $backend->{ $caller };
      return;
   },

   set => sub {
      my $var_ref = shift;
      my $data    = shift;

      my $backend = $data->{ backend };

      my $caller = _get_caller();

      $backend->{ $caller } = $$var_ref
      return;
   },
);

cast( our $Print, $wiz, default => 1 );


Disclaimer: All three of these interfaces are bad.

Hey I really don't mean to bother you, it doesn't matter at all but now I'm curious: why is that whole __PACKAGE__ replacement ordeal necessary? Won't __PACKAGE__ be always Z?

Is Z really your package name? It's going to change at least once. Anyway, DRY.

Ah I now see why, you want to automagically look for, say, $Namespaced_Package_Print in the caller in case the Z is actually named "Namespaced::Package", got it. Thanks again!

Since it's a package variable, you can use local to temporarily set the value of the state variable in every function that calls functions from Z instead of setting it globally in each other module:
sub f {
  local $Z::Print = 1; # Previous value will be restored when f returns
  Z::test(@_);
}

so you'd only have to rewrite X and Y, not Z.

I apologize I didn't manage to send my edit through before your answer came in, this is good advice in case there's not a whole load of functions to refactor (which is not the case and I'm sorry I didn't convey this efficiently enough), however still this lit up a bulb; Couldn't I just extend this to the whole X / Y module? As in local $Z::Print = 1; at the very start of X / Y / whatever module uses Z? Am I missing something?

@kos, No. There's only one $Z::Print, and a variable can't multiple values at the same time.  (Though see my answer for a way of making it look like it does...)

@kos You can use local at file scope, but it'll have the same issue your current code does - the value set in the last module loaded will be used.

RIght. sigh. @ikegami I'm slowly wrapping my head around your answer, perhaps that's exactly what I'm looking for.
